# Wrong values in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

In a Unity project the Visual Studio debugger reports the wrong value for a variable that just had its value assigned.
The expression on the right hand side reports the correct value when added as a watch.
The variable itself also holds the correct value(the code works), it's only a problem with the debugger.

What I already did:

- checked that I'm using the Debug configuration
- tried setting the platform to x86
- disabled JIT optimization
- manually added the symbol table
- switched between Visual Studio 2015 and 2017
- switched between Unity 2017.3 and 2018.1 beta

Seems like there is a problem with the Mathf managed library so also tried checking whatever seemed relevant in VS debugging config.

Comment: That is odd.  Could you add a couple more lines to the function to test the `test` variable against `5` and `22`?  Should help demonstrate if it's a problem with the debugger, or a problem with `RoundToInt()`.  Something such as `bool testIs5 = (test == 5); bool testIs22 = (test == 22);`

Comment: Why not copy and paste your actual script here. This will make sure that the problem is not on your side. Also restart both Unity and VS and see what happens

Comment: At this point, I would be adding multiple lines to call the `RoundToInt()` function (if indeed that is what it is) with various values to attempt to determine the behaviour of that mystery function.  Alternatively, maybe use ILSpy to load the assemblies from the `bin` folder and see if there are any oddities when navigating from this function's disassembly to `RoundToInt()`.  Also, maybe use the `System.Reflection` namespace to get a `MethodInfo` of `RoundToInt` to see what and where it lives.

Comment: Is there another variable named `test`, somewhere, by any chance?

Comment: This issue happened randomly to me. Please try to use the variable'test' in your code once, then debug it again, this time it will display correctly in watch window. After, it could work properly. That's my experience.

Comment: @Draba how is the issue going? In your case the function Mathf.RoundToInt referenced from third part dll,right? I wonder if it's the compatibility issue for debugger to evaluate the value inside of it. What if using Math.Round and converting it to Int type instead, same issue?